What does {:02} in Rust's println's formatting syntax do?
I'm reading the book "Rust in Action" and I came across these two lines in the sample code:
let forty_twos = [42.0, 42f32, 42.0_f32];
println!("{:02}", forty_twos[0]);

What does "{:02}" do in println!? If I replace it with "{}", the output remains the same.
I think it has something to do with formatting, but I can't be sure of that. There is no explanation in book and I don't know how to look for the answer in the documentation.

This is for printing leading zeros, see https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/ (where :04 is used as example).

https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/

See also: What is the difference between println's format styles?

See also: What is the easiest way to pad a string with 0 to the left?

This is used for printing leading zeros. Specifically it will pad the output string with 0 if it is less than 2 characters wide. Replacing it with "{}" didn't matter in this case since the value, 42, is already represented by two characters.
Changing it to "{:04}" for instance would print this:
0042

See the documentation at https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt.
